# What will be left if a latex sealant is mostly washed out before it can set?

Tags: waterproofing, sealant

I tried to seal an area by a door that puddles and leaks before tropical storm Henry arrived, but I made two mistakes:

- I applied [the sealant](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DAP-Dynaflex-Ultra-10-1-oz-Black-Advanced-Exterior-Window-Door-and-Siding-Sealant-18220/306283455) only 30 minutes before the storm hit (it needs 1 hour to dry, but given the humidity it would probably be longer)
- I used a latex sealant that can be cleaned with water

In retrospect I should have used a silicone based sealant ahead of time, but I was working within constraints.

24 hours into the rain, the leak is back. I checked on the sealant and it's mostly washed away, but residue remains in certain areas.

**Will whatever residue that remains eventually cure, or will I be left with a permanently soft mess that I need to remove before reapplying a new sealant?**

Comment: `Will xyz happen?` cannot be answered because nobody can see the future ... `could xyz happen?` is answerable ... just remove the residue and be sure

Comment: Assuming the residue cures (and I expect it will), latex sticks to latex just fine.

Comment: I would clean up the residual for its quality is questionable. Which is more expansive, a little more new sealant or leak?